# PHP dynamic class loading

Tags: php, class

Lets say that I have an array that I want to convert to a value object.

My value object class is as follows:

```
/* file UserVO.php*/
 class UserVO
 {
    public $id;
    public $email;

     public function __construct($data)
     {
         $this->id = (int)$data['id'];
         $this->email = $data['email'];
     } 
 }
```

And I create my array of value objects as follows:

```
/* file UserService.php*/
$array = array(
array(...),
array(...));
$count = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
   $result[] = new UserVO($array[$i]);
}
return $result;
```

OK, so this all works fine. However, I'd like to specificy the VO that is to be created dynamically, so that I can have a single dynamic function to create my VO's.

Something like:

```
$ret = create_vo($array, 'UserVO');

function create_vo($data, $vo)
{
  $count = count($data);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
     $result[] = new $vo($data[$i]); //this obviously wont work...Class name must be a valid object or a string
  }
  return $result;
}
```

I realise that I could do this with a switch statement (iterating through all my VO's)...but there is no doubt a much much more elegant solution. It would also be supercool if I could lazy load the VO's as needed, instead of having multiple 'includes'

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$result[] = new $vo($data[$i]); //this obviously wont work...Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

Have you tried it? It works just as expected (in php 5.1, I don't know how was it with OOP in php 4, but if you are using `__construct` for constructor this should work).

To avoid multiple includes define magic function `__autoload` before using any class

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    require_once 'myclasses/'.$className.'.php';
}
```

So first call `new UserVo` will trigger this function to include file **myclasses/UserVo.php**.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [include_once()'s and require_once()'s performance is pretty bad](http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2011/06/11/phps-include_once-is-insanely-expensive/).

My suggestion:

Kill all "require_once" and "include_once" and create an autoloader. Register this [implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: your auto loader still uses include or require it does does not load every thing constantly only when they are needed so your argument is not the most valid. as using the autoloader is more load.

Answer (score 0):

First, conversion of data to an array object for UserVO should be done with ArrayObject

so

```
class UserVO extends ArrayObject
{
}
```

You are trying to use the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and your code seems to be right, though you seem to have an forgotten to define $result as an array ($result = array()).

You can also use the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to pass constructor arguments as well as such:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass($vo);
$rc->newInstanceArgs($data[$i]);
```

To "autoload" your UserVO object, you should use the [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function with a php include path.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<?

class UserVO
{
    public $id;
    public $email;

    public function loadData($data)
    {
        $this->id = (int)$data['id'];
        $this->email = $data['email'];
    }
}

function create_vo($data, $vo)
{
    $count = count($data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $tmpObject = new $vo;
        $tmpObject->loadData($data[$i]);
        $result[] = $tmpObject;
        unset($tmpObject);
    }
    return $result;
}


$data = array();
$data[] = array('id'=>1,'email'=>'data@example.com');
$data[] = array('id'=>2,'email'=>'data@example.com');
$data[] = array('id'=>3,'email'=>'data@example.com');
$data[] = array('id'=>4,'email'=>'data@example.com');
$data[] = array('id'=>5,'email'=>'data@example.com');
$data[] = array('id'=>6,'email'=>'data@example.com');

$result = create_vo($data,'UserVO');

var_dump($result);

?>
```